# Flash Drive Mount

Tags: usb, mount, windows

I have a program that requires the USB installation drive to be plugged in when running the program. It works fine in windows just shows as a CD Drive.

In Ubuntu Disks it shows as Generic CD no media.

I suspect is has something to do with the way the program media is encrypted and write protected.

When I run lsblk in Terminal it doesn't even show up.

Any ideas?